# Selenium IDE 2.4.0 Unable to login via clickAndWait with input id

Tags: selenium

After the credentials have been successfully entered automatically, Selenium IDE is unable to login to the webapp using clickAndWait via the "btnLogin" input id (times out). As far as I know, nested frames are not being used.

Selenium IDE error info:

```
<Debug>
[info] Executing: |type | id=txtPassword | password |
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | id=btnLogin | | 
[error] Timed out after 30000ms


<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><input type="button" onclick="com.test.0x.LoginPage.login();"
value="Sign In" disabled="disabled" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin"
class="SigButton" style="width: 100px;"
onmouseover="this.className = 'SigButton SigButtonOver'"
onmouseout="this.className = 'SigButton'" /></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How long is the `ClickandWait` set for?

Comment: 30 secs I believe. Weird thing is that it just started working out of nowhere.

Comment: Glad to hear.  Nice when things work like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Did the browser actually load the page after the test had timed out? If it did then the timeout period may just need to be extended using the setTimeout coummand. In the example below the timeout period is changed to 60000 miliseconds.

```
<tr>
<td>setTimeout</td>
<td>60000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```